# Conditional statement on a flask user using flask-login

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I'm using `flask-login` and I want to hide/show some HTML in my template if the user is a certain user. Could use the ID in the `users` table to identify them.

I've been racking my brains but cant figure it out. What I basically wan to do is something like the following;

```
{% if current_user.id = 4728 %}
<p>Here is specific content only for user with ID 4728</p>
{% endif %}
```

Is this possible with flask login and jinja templates?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try replacing `{% if current_user.id = 4728 %}` with `{% if current_user.id == 4728 %}`. Notice you're comparing two values, so you use the 'equal to' operator.

Comment: Thats it! thanks so much